# MySQL DB opimise through php

Tags: php, mysql, database-optimization

Another little bit which I am missing (as a beginner) I have a Backup script between two DB and as a final step I should optimise the real DB to reduce the size of the overhead. I have a code which works when I use only one DB but I need to use two:

```
$actconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $actdbuser, $actdbpass) or die ('act Error connecting to mysql');
$bckconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $bckdbuser, $bckdbpass) or die (' back Error connecting to mysql');

$ressql="SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM $actdbname WHERE Data_free / Data_length > 0.1 AND Data_free >  102400";
```

- this should tell that bckuser is ignored, I believe...

```
 $res = mysql_query( $ressql, $actconn);

 echo mysql_error(); 
while($optrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  mysql_query('OPTIMIZE TABLE ' . $optrow['Name'], $actconn);
}
```

actconn value: Resource id #1

bckconn value: Resource id #2

mysql_error says:

> SELECT command denied to user 'bckuser'@'localhost' for table 'actual table'

any idea what I do wrong?

UPDATE:
bckuser should not do anything with it as actdbuser is the root of that DB, but some reason SHOW TABLE won't recognise $actconn...

UPDATE2:
I tried just the opt again and the only thing is changed is the $actdbname='db-name'; when working and $actdbname='`db-name`' with the spec apostrophe;

please note this is on sharedhost so I can't change the DB name.

thanks @Corbin interesting idea, I tried and didn't work, but how could I debug it? I can't even debug it properly some reason...

Comment: The error is quite explicit.., you should check permission of the user `bckuser`, it can't do `SELECT`.

Comment: thanks, please see the update part of it. bckuser should not touch this at all and actdbuser is root on that table

Comment: Hrmm, can you try passing true as a fourth parameter to the mysql_connect call?  I suspect that PHP is deciding to silently reuse the first connection.

Comment: thanks @Corbin interesting idea, I tried and didn't work, but how could I debug it? I can't even debug it properly some reason... how could I check that?

Comment: Hrmm, am not sure how to go about debugging that.  What it looks like to me is that instead of creating a second connection, PHP is re-logging in on the first connection.  That would explain why you're getting an error about the wrong user.  I guess the only way to be vaguely sure this is happening would be to make 100% sure that the right information is going into both connections and then determining what user each connection is running as.  Are you certain that $actdbuser contains what you think it does?

Comment: @Corbin, thanks well please find my UPDATE 2 in a minute - but somewhere here is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a proper grant permissions to user 'bckuser'@'localhost' for executing `SHOW TABLE STATUS` query.

Unfortunately in MySQL 5.5 there is no separate grant option for this operation. Alternatively you can grant `ALL` to this user or use `root` user login for doing this operation.
see [Grants Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

Comment: thanks, please see the update part of it. bckuser should not touch this at all.

Comment: try giving INSERT, SELECT grants  on table $actdbname.

Comment: I believe it is not the permission, either syntax error or something work with SHOW TABLES differently...